# rvm binstubs not working for irb?

Tags: ruby, rvm

Using latest version of RVM (1.29.3) and Ruby (2.4.1) under macOS High Sierra, `gem regenerate_binstubs` was applied, and though this works for ri, rdoc, and rake, it doesn't seem to have worked for other commands, including `irb`.

It should do though, shouldn't it?

Comment: Maybe your `PATH` isn't set like it used to be?

Comment: Hi tadman, thanks, but in this case it actually looks like the _irb_ shellscript wrapper hasn't been added to `~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/bin/irb`, and the same with the other commands there.  However it has been for _ri_, _rdoc_ and _rake_, so I'm not sure if a `$PATH` change would affect this?